# Does Ubuntu accept purely random incoming connections outside the LAN by default (meaning ufw is disabled)?

Tags: security

By "purely random," I mean that the connection was not initiated by the Ubuntu user.

EDIT: For example, think of a malicious SSH connection from a source outside the LAN.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide supporting output. Where are you seeing these incoming connections? How are you defining a connection?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Right now it's like playing darts blind folded. Please [edit] your question to include the details that Elder Geek requested and what your exact setup is along with what exactly you are concerned about here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by default, for user simplicity, the firewall UFW is disabled. 
Additionally, the host rules are set to receive and respond to ICMP, and other IPV4/6 requests.

To find out, you can do:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

and see if ufw is running.

Ubuntu also has IPtables, which may have default rules set, but I dont think it blocks malicious traffic. The term malicious traffic is subjective any given ip or subnet may or may not be malicious.

Comment: So, if UFW is disabled, Ubuntu would accept any malicious connection attempts outside the LAN? For example, a SSH connection.

Comment: @raffat That's not how this works. If you don't have an ssh server running then there's nothing to connect to. If you do have one running then yes, you should enable the firewall.

Comment: just enable it.  sudo ufw enable. I like to go into my hosts before.rules files, and set all the ICMP quench and whatever else to drop

Comment: @Seth being open to requests makes ones self a target. your PC needs to process the requests whether you have a service running or not. The way I see it typically goes down, is bots pass the target system, who has responded to unsolicited requests (ping) later, bots come and hammer all your ports, until something happens.

Comment: @j0h It's always a good idea to have a firewall running but if there is nothing listening on the port then the port is closed and that's the end of the story.

Comment: Your firewall (iptables / UFW) is just one layer of security.

Comment: @j0h - bots are automated attacks and you will see them in your logs regardless if your system responds to ping or not. DROP is no more secure the REJECT in iptables - see http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~peterb/network/drop-vs-reject Many of the tools available can determine your OS by how it responds to network traffic and DROP (the lack of a response) gives you away.

Answer (score 2):

By default there are "no open ports"

> Default installations of Ubuntu must have no listening network services after initial install.

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features#ports

SSH

opensh server is not installed by default.

If you install or configure a server, or servers, then, by default, the firewall (iptables/ufw) will accept new connections.

Security is then configured by server and can have several layers. It varies by server.

Using ssh you can build security into sshd_config, use keys, tcp wrapper, firewall ...

See http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/SSH_security

I will also vary via your network topology /router settings (UPnP, VPN)

HTTP

Again, you have several options here and can configure apache to accept traffic from your lan only, password protect directories, etc.

Google search security and server name.

Answer (score 0):

Purely random incoming connections from the outside of the LAN are not accepted by the router in most cases, because it wasn't told what to do with them.

**update**

If the ports are forwarded on the router to that exact Ubuntu host, then the connections are not random. (or the connections ARE random along with that random admin who forwards random ports)

**update**

If you don't owe or don't know the configuration of your LAN then various things can happen: ports can be forwarded, some network discovery may be activated.

Comment: What if the router's ports were forwarded? Then, if the connection was malicious, the security of the Ubuntu desktop would have to depend on its default settings.

Comment: My apologies for being unclear. The ports are forwarded for the Ubuntu host since an application needed to listen to them for it to function. However, someone may send packets to that application with a malicious intend.

Comment: detecting Malicious content is the job of an IDS http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44931/difference-between-ids-and-ips-and-firewall

Comment: As currently written, this answer assumes the LAN is separated from the Internet [by a *NAT* router](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). This is a common network topology but not the only one for connecting a LAN to the Internet. In particular, some businesses and universities, and even a few small home setups, "own" multiple IP addresses on the Internet, which they assign to multiple machines on the LAN. A router is still (usually) directing traffic between LAN and WAN, but unlike with NAT no port forwarding or DMZ is required for unsolicited traffic to get through.

Comment: You have to be very careful with this answer. Some routers have UpNP - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play so the presences of a router alone does not guarantee packets will not be forwarded. For this reason I am down voting this answer.